# Update the Android app to hide questions under ignored tags (when I have that setting enabled)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ignored-tags

On [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/), this is my tag blacklist:

> [image: ignored tags: bridge, and it's set to hide questions in my ignored tags]

Note well that I have them set to *hidden*, because I would prefer not to see questions on this topic. Bridge players, don't take offence — I don't have problem with the game itself. I don't understand the game's mechanics, though, so I find questions about it incomprehensible, and I'd rather stick to just seeing questions I can understand.

I still see [bridge] questions galore on the Android app though. Could it be updated to pay attention to whether I have certain tags ignored and set to be hidden?

Comment: I agree. I like to browse Arqade a lot, but I have [minecraft] tags filtered out because the sheer number of questions for that game drown out everything else. Because of this, browsing with the app is useless (to me) until it has the ability to filter out ignored tags.