# Hiding tags in the app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

While we're waiting for the Android app to be repaired ...

The browser UI lets us set both most and least favorite tags, and set a filter to hide questions carrying the latter. In some stacks I found that quite useful as a way of focusing on the questions I could actually contribute to or learn from.

As far as I can tell, the app doesn't have that filtering capability, despite needing it more due to smaller screens.

I presume it's on the list for eventual implementation. But sooner would be nice.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244196/update-the-android-app-to-hide-questions-under-ignored-tags-when-i-have-that-se?rq=1

Comment: @AndrewT. not related. Duplicate. :)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact you can't hide the questions with the tags you ignore, you can use the advanced search function in the app:

```
-[tag-to-hide] -[another-tag-to-hide] -[and-so-on]
```

in other words, put the minus sign before any tag you want to hide (the spaces are not required and I added the, just for the visibility).